# How to indent c++ template declaration in Qt

Tags: c++, uncrustify

I am using Qt with uncrustify c++ code beautifier plugin. I want to give indentation after the template declaration as given below

```
template<typename T>
  void f(){}
```

and not:

```
template<typename T>
void f(){}
```

I have tried but couldn't find a solution. How do I achieve that using Uncrustify or some other mean?

Comment: I modified your tags, removing `Qt` and `Qt5` since I think that your question has nothing to do with Qt, but instead it is related to `Uncrustify` working on `C++`